# Order of ROUNDING

Tags: sql

I have two diff queries as,

Round before * 100

```
    SELECT ds,
       ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN action = 'accepted' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) * 1.0 / 
             COUNT(action),2) * 100 as pre_accpt
FROM friend_requests
GROUP by 1
```

Round after * 100

```
select ad_id, coalesce(Round(total_clicks * 1.0 / (total_clicks + total_views) * 100,2),0) as ctr
from (
    
    select ad_id, 
           count(case when action = 'Clicked' then 1 else NULL end) as total_clicks,
           count(case when action = 'Viewed' then 1 else NULL end) as total_views
    from ads
    group by 1) a
    order by 2 desc
```

They both give me correct output but wanted to understand when its better to round? Is it better to round before * 100 in this use case when you want to keep more precision? ( keeping .666667 as 66.66)

Thanks

Comment: Round last. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Consider what happens with something where the digits don't repeat.